# Tilde over greek letter in text

Tags: accents, greek, text-mode

how can I get a tilde over the greek letter nu in text. I am using:

```
\usepackage{textgreek}
```

I tried

```
\~\textnu
```

but that gives the tilde in front of the letter and not above it.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a minimal working example (MWE) to your question? I just tried `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{textgreek}\begin{document}\~\textnu\end{document}`, and that does indeed produce a tilde above the letter, as intended.

Comment: @chsk I don't get it. And, knowing how `\~` is defined, it cannot work.

Comment: @egreg That's really strange. I just tried again, and even though it perhaps _cannot_ work, it definitely _does_. What gives?

Comment: For later reference, this is because I was using xetex (where using `textgreek` is not a good idea to begin with). Thanks to David Carlisle and Ulrike Fischer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the LGR encoding for the job, using the fact that the tilde accent exists in it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textgreek}

\newcommand{\tildenu}{{\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont\accperispomeni\textnu}}

\begin{document}

\tildenu

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the tilde like in the Latin font, you have to go the hard way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textgreek}

\newcommand{\tildenu}{%
  \leavevmode\vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr\~{}\cr\noalign{\kern-1ex}\textnu\cr}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\tildenu

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, just a curiosity. Why in my screenshot have the tilde not true bold than your (your first screenshot) :-)? Is it your MacOS? :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano They're the same, only at different resolutions.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much for your explanation.

Answer (score 8):

Probabily you can use this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\begin{document}
\textgreek{o\~nios}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
$\tilde{\nu}$
```

or

```
$\widetilde{\nu}$
```

Answer (score 5):

With XeLaTeX you could use

```
\textnu\char"0303
```

or (provided that you load a font that supports Greek)

```
\char"03BD\char"0303
```

Comment: Or you could directly use `ν̃` which is more readable.

Comment: Indeed.Then you need to have the file Unicode encoded of course.